# Use of index in pandas DataFrame for groupby and aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to aggregate a single column DataFrame and count the number of elements. However, I always end up with an empty DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]}).groupby("A").count()

Out[46]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If I add a second column, I get the desired result:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5], "B":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]}).groupby("A").count()

Out[45]: 
   B
A   
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  3
```

Can you explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]}).groupby("A")["A"].count())
```

prints

```
A
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    3
```

Comment: Can you explain, what the difference is between `groupby("A")` and `groupby("A")["A"]`?

Comment: Please see the return types of both calls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the grouped by column in your result:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]}).groupby("A").A.count()
```

Output:

```
A
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    3
```